# Why Spring Boot throws different exceptions for Controller method argument validations?

Tags: spring-boot

While validating a primitive type or their equivalent (Integer, Boolean) using constraints validation annotations (@Min, @NotNull, ...) Spring Boot throws `ConstraintViolationException`. But when validating a parameter using the `@Valid` annotation then `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown.

I have a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` to handle the exceptions from the Controllers.
The problem is that depending on the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version, the results are pretty much different.
While using the version `2.0.5.RELEASE` I just needed to include a handler for the `ConstraintViolationException` class.
But there are some others versions that `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown too.

It already was mentioned on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web/issues/3), but no useful answer...

I'll use the lukasniemeier-zalando's example here. For more detail click on the link above.

```java
 @Validated  // needed to actually trigger validation
 @RestController
 class MyController {

   @RequestMapping
   Response serve(
     @RequestParam @Min(2) Integer parameter,  // throws ConstraintViolationException
     @RequestBody @Valid BodyModel body        // throws MethodArgumentNotValidException
     ) {
       return new Response();
     }

 }
```

I would expect that both validations throws the same exception, no matter which of them, just to be consistent.

Apearently there's no reason to this to be like it is, at least it was what I understood from this other [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10471).

Then I just want a answer why Spring Boot throws 2 types of exception to represent the same problem (argument validation).

**Note**: as mentioned before, using the version `2.0.5.RELEASE` of the `spring-boot-starter-parent` it doesn't happens.

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
```

But as reported by the last GitHub issue that I linked, the version `2.0.0.M4` has this behavior, and I also experienced it with the `2.2.0.M3` version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are handled by different validation mechanisms. The `@Validated` on the class is handled by the [`MethodValidationInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.html) which is a **generic purpose validation mechanism** for classes. Due to this it throws a `ConstraintViolationException`. The `@Validated` is used here simply because the [`@Valid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) annotation isn't allowed on types. Hence the only way to enable/trigger the `MethodValidationInterceptor` is by using the `@Validation` annotation.

The `@Valid` on the method argument in a controller is handled by the [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) internally and leads to a **web specific binding exception**, the [`MethodArgumentNotValidException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html). The `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` is called (indirectly) from the [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) when preparing the method invocation. Instead of `@Valid` you could also use the `@Validated` annotation on the method argument. Spring MVC supports both (it actually supported `@Validated` before `@Valid` even existed!).

The solution/workaround is to create your own exception-handler which handles the `ConstraintViolationException` the same as a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. Which is also suggested in the GitHub issue you link to.

Comment: That's crazy!

Why `@Validated`, a Spring specific annotation, throws `ConstraintViolationException`, an exception from Bean Validation API; and `@Valid`, an annotation from Bean Validation API, throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, a Spring specific exception?

The opposite would be understandable, since the docs from `@Validated` says:

> [...] **not** JSR-303 specific.

Then it's ok to throw other exception, because that's not directly linked to JSR-303.  
The way it is now a days makes no sense to me...  
May you explain, please?

Comment: The annotations don't throw anything. YOu cannot use `@Valid` on types and hence you need `@Validated` as a trigger for the interceptor (annotations are merely metadata). THe `@Valid` on the method argument can also be an `@Validated` Spring supports both on method arguments and both are handled the same, due to the simple fact they are only suported on controllers which are web bases. It throws a web specific exception. Also springs validation pre-dates JSR-303 and as stated the annotation is for validating web related model attributes.

Comment: I don't know if that changed lately, but today it is possible to use @Valid on types. At least it is possible to annotate types. It has just no effect, as far as I can tell. But good question and answer though!

Comment: This relates to Spring's `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` which doesn't handle `ConstraintViolationException`. @M.Deinum Is it expected behaviour? Or is it expected that users will always handle the `ConstraintViolationException` themselves?